# Print Var in JsFiddle

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

How would I print something to the result screen in JsFiddle from my JavaScript. I can't use `document.write()`, it doesn't allow it, neither `print`.

What should I use?

Comment: Check out this example. http://jsfiddle.net/jadiagaurang/m58Rn/

Comment: @GaurangJadia That's handy, you should add it as an answer (the only problem is `console.log()` accepts arguments differently than your custom function).

Comment: This is essentially a need for console.log() ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get console inside jsfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130610/how-to-get-console-inside-jsfiddle)

Comment: Nowadays jsfiddle allows the use of document.write()

Answer (score 502, accepted):

To be able to see output from `console.log()` in JSFiddle, go to **External Resources** on the left-side panel and add the following link for Firebug:

https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js

[image: Example of the result after adding firebug-lite-debug.js]

Comment: Fabulous answer.  Basically splits the output pane into two panes.

Comment: This is fantastic, i wish i knew about that sooner. Huge thanks!

Comment: I wish JSFiddle would do this by default, or at least have a very obvious checkbox to enable it with one click.

Comment: the console only shows up after you've run the code for the first time! great answer btw!

Comment: best answer in the world.

Comment: Is there anything like this for Chrome ? Actually JSFiddle should support something like this out of the box, it would be pretty helpful.

Comment: This is it! Outstanding answer, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: If I could upvote this for every time I referred back here, you'd be a god

Comment: Confirming with @PeterPiper, hit "run" twice to get the console/firebug tabs. Also be aware of the tabs, if you click on an object to see details, when you run again, it will remain on the "DOM" tab, click back on the console tab to see the results of another "run" unless you want to see the entire Dom object!

Comment: Nothing can beat this answer!

Answer (score 69):

[I have a template for this purpose](http://jsfiddle.net/IQAndreas/qsPEc/1/); here is the code I use:

### HTML

```
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

### JavaScript

```
function out()
{
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += args.join(" ") + "\n";
}
```

### Sample use (JavaScript)

```
out("Hello world!");
out("Your lottery numbers are:", Math.random(), 999, Math.PI);
out("Today is", new Date());
```

Comment: And to pritty print objects...

out(JSON.stringify(myObject, null, 2));

Comment: Note that this will have problems with unescaped '<' or '>' characters, and that it will also barf when argument values are <undefined>. This may not be an issue for your use case, but something to be aware of when replacing calls to console.log().

Comment: Improved version: uses `innerText` instead of `innerHTML` and send the log to the original console as well:`function newLog(oldLog) {
  return function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    document.getElementById('console-log').innerText += args.join(" ") + "\n";
    oldLog.apply(this, args)
  }
}
console.log = newLog(console.log)
console.error = newLog(console.error)` [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wdgfnn0h/2/)

Comment: Somehow this shows nothing to me when trying in jsfiddle. :(

Comment: @Suma Hm, there might be a JavaScript error. It runs fine on my machine, but you might be using a different version. Try opening the debug console and look for errors (make sure to hit the **Run** button in the top left corner when doing so)

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't seem to expose the document object

Answer (score 39):

Try:

```
document.getElementById('element').innerHTML = ...;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HKhw8/

Comment: You can use `document.getElementById('element').innerHTML += [stuff here] + "<br/>";` if you want to have multiple lines and **add** information to the page, instead of just replacing the old information.

Answer (score 27):

Might not do what you do, but you can type

```
console.log(string)
```

And it will print the string into the console of your *browser*. In chrome push <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to open the console.

Comment: Or you can use `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`K` if you want the console to be docked at the bottom of the page, instead of floating around in a separate window.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/chY5y/

```
$('body').append(yourVariable);
```

Comment: Hhmmm, doesn't work... how would I print out simple text along with a variable

Answer (score 7):

Now jsfiddle can do it from the scratch. Just go to Javascrpt --> Frameworks & extensions --> Jquery(edge) and check Firebug lite checkbox

Comment: But I loose syntax highlighting with this :(

Answer (score 5):

document.body.innerHTML = "Your data";

Comment: Better yet, do a += to append.  I.e.,: `document.body.innerHTML += "Your data" + "<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += "Even more data" + "<br/>";`

Answer (score 4):

With ES6 tricks could be

```
function say(...args)
{ 
    document.querySelector('#out').innerHTML += args.join("</br>");
}
say("hi","john");
```

Add only

```
 <span id="out"></span>
```

in HTML

Answer (score 3):

Here's one alternative: http://jsfiddle.net/skibulk/erh7m9og/1/

```
document.write = function (str) {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", str);
}

document.write("¡hola mundo");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something that might be useful to some folks....

If you add the debugger console as shown above, you can access the scope by executing this:

scope = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller=MyCtrl]')).scope();

I find inspecting the scope directly easier than console.log, alert(), etc.

Comment: do you have an example usage, I dont follow.

Comment: I have no idea why I answered with an Angular answer, wrong thread I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JSfiddle, you can use this library: https://github.com/IonicaBizau/console.js

Add a rawgit of the lib to your jsfiddle resources: 
 `https://cdn.rawgit.com/IonicaBizau/console.js/0ee8fcc4ea802247c5a7a8e3c6530ede8ade308b/lib/console.min.js`

Then you can just add this in the HTML:
`<pre class="console"></pre>`

Initialize the console in your JS:
`ConsoleJS.init({selector: "pre.console"});`

Usage Example: See it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6f2ubLgv/)

```
ConsoleJS.init({selector: "pre.console"});

let b;

console.log('hello world');
console.log([{'a':10,'b':44}]);
console.log(typeof [1,2,3,4]);
console.log(50 +67);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this isn't an answer or upvoted in the comment by Rubén

> Nowadays jsfiddle allows the use of document.write() –  Rubén  Jul 16,
> 2018 at 19:05

Adding it as an answer for anyone looking.

Answer (score -4):

Use the `alert()` function:

```
alert(variable name);
alert("Hello World");
```

Comment: alert is never a good debugging tool -- does not show objects, interrupts behavior of the code, etc etc