# Fiddle not working javascript

Tags: javascript

Why is the fiddle not printing in console:

HTML:

```
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="validateEmail();" />
```

JavaScript

```
function validateEmail() {
    console.log("ABC\n");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/amandeepautam/HKhw8/539/

Reference: [Print Var in JsFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382200/print-out-a-var-in-jsfiddle)

Comment: because the function isn't on the global scope.

Comment: Why doesn't your fiddle match the code in your question? that's a bit confusing. Different problem entirely.

Comment: you're welcome http://jsfiddle.net/HKhw8/538/

Comment: @KevinB changed the fiddle

Comment: Regarding your edit, the function doesn't exist at the time the onclick event is bound. Under "Frameworks and Extensions", change "On Load" to "In Head". [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/HKhw8/540/).

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam You're trying to use jQuery without linking to it.  You can enable it either from the dropdown in "Frameworks and Extensions" or by adding "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" to the "External Resources".

Comment: jQuery is not required in the OP's edited post.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's an error in the script: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Seems you need to reference JQuery (its in "Frameworks & Extensions" dropdown)