# Why can't I run the codes?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I wrote

```
function factorial(n) {
    if (n === 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return n * factorial(n - 1); 
}

console.log(factorial(3));
```

the codes is calculate factorial.

But I wrote the code in jsfiddle and run, nothing happens.
And I wrote html like

```
<script>
   function factorial(n) {
           ・
　　　　　　 ・
　　console.log(factorial(3));
</script>
```

and when it is browsed in GoogleChrome,nothing shows in console.I want to see 6 in console.log.6 is calculated by 1*2*3. What is wrong in my codes?How should I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print Var in JsFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382200/print-var-in-jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It runs for me. Try putting your script tag inside `<body>`.

```
<html>
  <head><title>Does it run?</title></head>
<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>

  <script>
  function factorial(n) {
    if (n === 0) {
      return 1;
    }
    return n * factorial(n - 1); 
  }
  console.log(factorial(3));
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, but jsfiddle, by default, doesn't display console output.

You can fix this by clicking on the left and adding a resource such as https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js then run your code and you should see the console output.

See this question for reference --> [Print Var in JsFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382200/print-var-in-jsfiddle)

Comment: Edit: This may be a duplicate. The poster was asking if there was something wrong with his/her code. I explained that the problem was with the interface and showed a link to a question explaining how to enable a feature that he/she was looking for.

Comment: @JaromandaX you're actually correct literally, though, personally you seem like you're trying to be offensive. I edited my answer to better help OP.

Comment: @JaromandaX I'll stand by that your comments are trying to be offensive without  asking for clarification or pointing out problems in the post.

Comment: @JaromandaX You deleted both of your previous comments because they were offensive. Now, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? There's a reason stackoverflow has a reputation for being hostile towards new users. Let's try to be part of the solution, not the problem.

Comment: Put it this way - you edited your error in response to my comment - so clearly my comment was correct - if you take a look at the "accepted" answer however, it's hard to say what the OP was having an issue with - I believe they put the script in the script box in jsfiddle with script tags!!

Answer (score 0):

For jsFiddle one approach that works reasonably well is creating an output div and a log function

A simple way would be

HTML

```
<div id="output"><div>
```

CSS

```
#output{ white-space: pre-line;}
```

JavaScript

```
let output = document.querySelector("#output"),
log = (t) => output.textContent += t + "\r\n";
```